# Set Color jquery

Tags: jquery

> It is assumed that all checkboxes have information related . Put color
>   `#9cf` background color text boxes check. In addition , insert the
>   string Additional Options  before the text boxes . Note: In these forms
>   the format for a box verification is:
>
> ```
> <p><input type="checkbox" NAME="nombre" VALUE="Si"> HOLA </br> </p>
> ```

I have done is this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").after("Aditional Options");    

$("input[type=checkbox]").css("background-color", "#9cf");
```

But my problem is that I dont know how to establish`#9cf` background color to the word "HOLA"

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Have you tried applying `css()` to the `<p>` element?

Comment: you can try this. 
$('p').css({"background-color":"#9cf"});

Comment: Just Jquery is allowed in this exercice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply color to the HOLA only, I would recommend wrapping it into a `<label></label>` tag. This would also make it easier for users to check the checkbox.

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" NAME="nombre" VALUE="Si" id="checkbox_hombre">
    <label for="checkbox_hombre">HOLA</label> </br> 
</p>
```

Note the "for" attribute in the label and "id" attribute in the input tag.

Then you can apply color to the label:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").next('label').css("background-color", "#9cf");
```

If you need to apply color to labels of checked checkboxes only, try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").next('label').css("background-color", "#9cf");
```